# Are the roots of an infinitely divisible probability infinitely divisible themselves?

Tags: pr.probability, lie-groups, topological-groups, semigroups-and-monoids, convolution

> Let $\mu$ be an infinitely divisible probability on a topological group $G$. If $\nu ^{* n} = \mu$ for some $n$, is $\nu$ an infinitely divisible probability too?

A sufficient criterion would be to show that $\mu$ can be continuously embedded into a one-parameter convolution semigroup, in which case the answer to my question would be affirmative. This approach has two inconveniences: it replaces my question with an even more complicated one, and it offers the answer in a very indirect way. Are there more straightforward answers to this question, answers "closer to first principles"?

Alternatively, is it possible to isolate rich classes of topological groups for which the question has an affirmative answer, again without going through the continuous embedding problem? Lie groups would be the first to look at, but not the only ones.

Comment: in $Z_3$ $\delta_0  = \delta_2^{*3}$ and the former is infinitely divisible while the latter is not.  Cross with a finer group, if you like